# Implement SBPL_lattice_planner in ROS2 Foxy

Tags: c++, cmake, ros, ros2

When I implement SBPL so has error:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we **discourage images** which represents code, error messages and other **textual** information. Instead, we expect the question post to contain the text itself. Please, (re-)read [ask] and edit the question post accordingly.

Comment: A picture of an error is not enough to actually debug what's going on here.